# cant config correct mongo db name in spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Im currently diving in MongoDB and Spring.
Although another db is configured, it still tries to create/read from the wrong db.

Here's my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class MongoConfig {

  @Bean
  public MongoClientFactoryBean mongo() {
    MongoClientFactoryBean mongo = new MongoClientFactoryBean();
    mongo.setHost("localhost");
    return mongo;
  }

  @Bean
  public MongoOperations mongoTemplate(Mongo mongo) {
      return new MongoTemplate(mongo, "gabble");
  }
}
```

Handler:

```
@Component
public class SomeHandler {
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SomeHandler.class);
  private MongoOperations mongo;


  @Autowired
  public SomeHandler(MongoOperations mongo) {
      this.mongo = mongo;
  }

  public void registerNewUser(User user, Credential credential) {       
    log.info(mongo.getCollectionNames());

    mongo.save(user,"user");
    mongo.save(credential,"credential");

    log.info("count: "+mongo.getCollection("user").count());
    log.info("content: "+mongo.getCollection("user").find());
    log.info("stored new user in database");
  }
}
```

the output of log.info():

```
2016-08-03 14:46:13 INFO  SomeHandler:29 - count: 1
2016-08-03 14:46:13 INFO  SomeHandler:30 - content: Cursor id=0, ns=test.user, query={ }, numIterated=0, readPreference=primary
```

As you can see, mongo object refers to test.user, but why ? 
Is there more configuration needed ? The db test gets also created by spring.

Comment: Do you have spring boot in that project? Are you sure your `MongoConfig` is executed? Because it seems like `MongoTemplate` is actually auto-configured by spring boot.

Comment: yep, Im using spring boot. I already tracked  down, that it seems to be caused by `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. But if i remove this, my whole application is not starting anymore. Im currently looking for workaround or some pointers how to manage this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using spring boot, you can just use its [auto-configuration capabilities](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb) - add the following line to the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/gabble
```

and remove the `MongoConfig` class entirely.